# POX - Installing a rule which says to send a dummy packet whenever a certain packet matches an ofp_match

Tags: python, tcp, openflow, sdn, pox

Is it possible to install a rule on a switch that instructs the switch to do the following:

```
If packet_in is TCP:
    send ( dummy packet )
    send (packet_in)
    send ( dummy packet)
else:
    send (packet_in)
```

I appreciate that that's pretty poor pseudo code, but it should illustrate what I'm trying to do a bit better than me trying to explain it.

Basically I'm trying to space out the transmission of TCP packets for a project by transmitting dummy packets, without having to require every TCP packet to be sent to the controller. I want the switch to behave as normal, but when it recieves a TCP packet destined for a certain port, I want the switch to also transmit a dummy packet (which I have constructed) out of the same port, headed for the same destination.

I understand that there may be some better ways to do what I'm trying to achieve - I'm open to suggestions!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know the answer is no OpenFlow does not support this concept let alone Pox. Pox can tell a switch to generate a packet but there is no flow table entry with an action of send this other packet over here.

A possible way this could be implemented is as follows though:

1. Match on the TCP protocol and port number have two actions. Action number one send the packet, action number 2 send the packet to some spare table for flow tables.
2. In this table have an action to modify the packet to send this dummy packet. You could not craft a specific one but you could say modify the destination IP to some nonsense value or set some nonsense VLAN as a kind of sudo marker.

Edit:
User asked for clarification on what I meant by a spare table so I will try to find some pox commands to show the process I planned on using.
First off I would suggest [this](https://openflow.stanford.edu/display/ONL/POX+Wiki) wiki for a lot of the basic pox commands it's a bit dated and in some cases is wrong but over all it is very useful.

When stating a spare table I am talking about the concept that openflow 1.3 enabled which says all flow tables do not have to be a single list for processing. Instead all packets can go to table 0 for processing then if an action states it can send the packet to say table 5 for extended processing or a more targeted processing based on what table 0 found. This allows more versatile actions, you can think of this new concept as a table of tables or a 2d array where the final elements are flow table entries. Sorry the word table comes up a lot I wish they chose a different word for this concept.

Pox by default does not support this concept since it uses OpenFlow1.0 however there is an extension that enables it and more information on that can be found [here](https://haryachyy.wordpress.com/2014/06/07/learning-pox-openflow-controller-l2-switch-using-multiple-tables/). Some of the important pieces can be found below.

```
# Turn on Nicira packet_ins
msg = nx.nx_packet_in_format()
event.connection.send(msg)
# Turn on ability to specify table in flow_mods
msg = nx.nx_flow_mod_table_id()
event.connection.send(msg)
msg = nx.nx_flow_mod()
msg.priority = 1 # Low priority
msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port = of.OFPP_CONTROLLER))
msg.actions.append(nx.nx_action_resubmit.resubmit_table(table = 1))
event.connection.send(msg)
msg = nx.nx_flow_mod()
msg.table_id = 1
msg.priority = 1 # Low priority
msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_output(port = of.OFPP_FLOOD))
event.connection.send(msg)
```

In this example multi table support is enabled, then a flow is added which sends all packets to the controller and table 1, from there table 1 has a flow which says flood all packets. Hopefully this gives you a general idea on how they work.

Incase you do not already know how to edit packets with pox an example action which can be appended to the actions list to change the destination mac address would be as follows.

```
ofp_action_dl_addr.set_dst(EthAddr("01:02:03:04:05:06"))
```

For vlan the method I proposed earlier you could do

```
msg.actions.append(of.ofp_action_vlan_vid(vlan_vid=1234))
```

Comment: Arduic, thanks! I think I grasp the main idea of your implementation suggestion, however I am confused as to what you mean by 'some spare table for flow tables'. Could you possibly elaborate for me?

Comment: I edited the post to contain a brief explanation on multi table concepts in OpenFlow/Pox. As well as some sample code to help you try and implement what I was proposing.

Comment: That's great, thanks. I had a feeling you might be talking about Nicira - this is something I briefly looked into after reading your initial answer last night, but I'll have to look into it some more. 

Is the example that you provided specific to the implementation you suggested or just an example?? Would it be possible to install a rule on one table which sends the packet as is, then forward the packet to another table which then edits the VLAN header and forwards it as a dummy?

I could then have another rule installed on every switch stating that all packets with that VLAN ID are dropped?

Comment: Yep that is all possible. As in my excerpt above you could replace the port=of.OFPP_CONTROLLER with just port=3 or what ever destination you want. Then leave the table=1, this essentially inserts 2 actions for this flow and both are followed. In the second table you could just have a generic catch all match with the vlan edit as I proposed and again a port=3 or what have you and on the machine at the end node it would see 2 packets one with a vlan and one without. Remember vlan was just a single option you can edit almost anything in the packet header so there may be something more suited.

Comment: So to be clear that was just an example it showed the basic concept of how to use the Nicira extension for multi table support. Think of this table action as just another action similar to how you can send one packet to multiple hosts by having 2 actions one for port 3 and one for port 4 it is just another generic action.

Comment: Thanks for your useful insight and advice - it's appreciated!

Comment: One last question - are there any other things I must add to my code to enable the use of the nicira features? I understand I have to import it as usual, however do I need to pass an extra argument to the command line when starting my controller up?

Comment: Once imported it should work without any extra command line options. Just remember that first block of code I sent is an example that would be placed in the ConnectionUp event. Until a switch receives the first two sends in that block of code it will not understand the packets being sent. Once sent though you do not need to repeat every time.

Comment: So once i specify that, does it mean that subsequent ofp messages wont work, and they'll all have to be nx messages?

Comment: At the moment when I'm adding the `msg = nx.nx_packet_in_format()
event.connection.send(msg)` lines, subsequent pings arent reaching their destination and the following message appears in the log 
INFO:openflow.of_01:Vendor msg: ofp_vendor_generic
  header:
    version: 1
    type:    4 (OFPT_VENDOR)
    length:  92
    xid:     0
  vendor: 8992
  datalen: 80

Comment: hmmmm not sure I would suggest reading the guide I linked. To be fair I implemented this on an older version of OvS and on Pox dart version. https://haryachyy.wordpress.com/2014/06/07/learning-pox-openflow-controller-l2-switch-using-multiple-tables/
Both ofp and nx messages should work in tandum nx should not break ofp if it does something has gone wrong. It's possible when nx packets are first enabled they break any old flows check if you still have flows on the switch.

Comment: Oh I see... Is the whole block of code that you sent meant to be in the ConnectionUp handler?? I think I understand now. But what I need to do is to be able to make sure only TCP packets are paced. And only if a certain condition is met... Would this be possible?

Comment: Yes yes both of those questions are correct. My example was just to show you how to enable this concept in Pox I'm not going to write everything for you that's up to you.

Comment: Of course, not expecting you to write everything. I was just confused because I've never installed rules in the Connection up handler before. 

I think if I install a rule in the connection up Handler to forward all other packets as normal, and send TCP packets to the controller, then have the PacketIn handler add the multiple table rules for the TCP/VLAN match combination it should work that way. I just need to find a way for the rules instaleld at the PacketIn handler to overwrite the 'forward to controller rule' set in the ConnectionUp Handler...

Comment: Hi arduic, do you know anything about the nx_match feature?